# Should I install 10 AWG or re-use the existing 8 AWG?

Tags: electrical, wiring, kitchens, appliances, oven

My new built in oven uses a 30 amp/10AWG wiring connection. My old oven has 40 amp/8 AWG wiring.

Is it possible to use this connection with just switching a breaker?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, by all means - larger than minimum wire is perfectly fine.

Comment: The breaker protects the wire which is why oversized wire is okay, but an oversized breaker is not.